# Add several textviews over multiple lines

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, textview

I have a LinearLayout where I append textviews programmatically. The problem is that the number of textviews and the content (one word in each view) are dynamic. 
How can I start to append the next textview to a new line, if the current line is filled?

Would like:

```
One Textview for each 
word almost like a 
page in a book
```

This example should give 12 textviews, with a new line after "each" and "a" becauce "word" and "page" are to long to fit on the previous line.

My code is:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        llp.setMargins(15, 0, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

    for(int k=0; k<words.size(); k++)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setTypeface(font);
        tv.setText(words.get(k));
        tv.setTextSize(20.0f);
        tv.setLayoutParams(llp);

        tv_holder_layout.addView(tv); //Add view to layout
        wordTextViews.add(tv); //Add TextView to arraylist, to be able to find it later
    }
```

the "`tv_holder_layout`" is simple `LinearLayout` (horizontal) for now...

Comment: I understood your question but could you let me know why do you want to use a separate TextView for each word?

Comment: I guess `clickListener` for every word

Comment: Oh, sorry. The words are to be found in a kind of puzzle, and when a word is found, I add a strike through that word...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a vertical `LinearLayout` that will hold the other `LinearLayout`s that each of them will represent a line.

You can evaluate the width of the a textview before rendering it by calling

```
view.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
```

after you know the width you can add your views, depending on how wide each line

Comment: You mean to add horizontal linear layouts with textviews to the vertical layout?
Then I need to measure the horizontal layout and add to the width of the new textview... If layout+textview > parent width, then add new horizontal layout...?